# Why my database connection failes during unit test processing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Despite struggling to make my UT works by trying every possibilities I find on the net, I still don't understand how to make it works. Here is my code and the stack I'm using :

**Stack:**

- NodeJS 18
- Express
- Sequelize
- MySQL
- JSONWebToken
- Docker
- Mocha
- Chai
- ChaiHttp

**Code:**

Unit test file `UserController.spec.js` :

```
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
import chai from "chai";
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import app from "../src/app.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

describe("Test all the trainer controller route. ", function () {
    describe("Test /users route with post method", function () {
        it("should return code response 201", async function (done) {
            const trainer = {
                firstname: "Mike",
                lastname: "SMITH",
                birthdate: "1988-12-03 00:00:00",
                login: "msmith",
                password: await bcrypt.hash("yacine", await bcrypt.genSalt(5))
            }
            chai.request(app)
                .post("localhost:80/users")
                .send(trainer)
                .end((err, res) => {
                    res.should.have.status(201);
                    res.should.have.be.a("object");
                    res.should.have.property("message").eql("Trainer with the login: " + trainer.login + " created successfully.");
                    res.should.have.property("firstname");
                    res.should.have.property("lastname");
                    res.should.have.property("birthday");
                    res.should.have.property("login");
                    res.should.have.property("password");
                    done();
                });
        });
    })
});
```

Here is my `index.js`:

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import app from './src/app.js';
import db_sequelize from './src/Database.js';
import models from './src/models/index.js';
void models;

// db 
// connect to db

(async () => {
    try {
        await db_sequelize.authenticate();
        await db_sequelize.sync(); // synchronisation modèles / tables
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
        const created = await db_sequelize.sync();
        if (created)
            console.log("tous les tables sont créés avec succès");
        add_admin();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }
})()


// app
app.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 80');
})
//admin creation
async function add_admin() {

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(5);
    const admin_found = await models.Trainer.findOne({
        where: {
            login: 'leopkmn',
        }
    });
    if (!admin_found) {
        const admin = await models.Trainer.create({
            firstname: 'Leo',
            lastname: 'Pokemaniac',
            birthdate: '1999-10-08',
            login: 'leopkmn',
            password: bcrypt.hashSync("cynthia", salt)
        });
        console.log("admin created");
        await models.Trainer_right.create({
            id_trainer: admin.id,
            users_create: true,
            users_read: true,
            users_update_self: true,
            users_update_all: true,
            users_delete_self: true,
            users_delete_all: true
        });
        await models.Trade_right.create({
            id_trainer: admin.id,
            trade_create_self: true,
            trade_create_all: true,
            trade_read: true,
            trade_update_self: true,
            trade_update_all: true
        });
        await models.Pokemon_right.create({
            id_trainer: admin.id,
            pokemons_create_all: true,
            pokemons_create_self: true,
            pokemons_read: true,
            pokemons_update_self: true,
            pokemons_update_all: true,
            pokemons_delete_self: true,
            pokemons_delete_all: true
        });
        await models.Log_right.create({
            id_trainer: admin.id,
            logs_read: true,
        });
        await models.Log.create({ type_of_action: "initiation", description: "admin registed" + admin.id })

    }
}
```

Here is my `app.js`:

```
import express from 'express';
// import mysql from 'mysql';
import usercontroller from './controllers/UserController.js';


const app = express();

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.status(404).send('Not found');
})

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/', usercontroller);
// routes 

export default app;
```

Here is my `UserController.js` file:

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import Trainer from '../models/Trainer.js';
import Trainer_right from '../models/Trainer_right.js';
import Pokemon_right from '../models/Pokemon_right.js';

import Trade_right from '../models/Trade_right.js';
import Log from '../models/Log.js';

// import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
// import { check, validationResult } from 'express-validator';
const router = Router();

router.post("/users", async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const doesTrainerExist = await Trainer.findOne({
        where: {
            login: body.login
        }
    });
    const isEmpty = Object.values(body).some(prop => prop == null || prop.length == 0 || prop == undefined);
    if (isEmpty) {
        return res.status(400).json( { message: "missing parameters !"} );
    }
    else if (doesTrainerExist) {
        return res.status(422).json({ message: "Trainer with the login: " + body.login + " already exist."});
    }
    else {
        /**
         * TODO
         * check if the user is authenticated
         * check if the user has the users.create right to make this operation
         */
        const trainer = {
            firstname: body.firstname,
            lastname: body.lastname,
            birthdate: body.birthdate,
            login: body.login,
            password: await bcrypt.hash(body.password, await bcrypt.genSalt(5))
        }
        await Trainer.create(trainer)
        return res.status(201).json({ message: "Trainer with the login: " + trainer.login + " created successfully." });
    }
})

export default router;
```

Here is my Database.js connection file:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
const db_info = {
     host: 'db',
     user: 'root',
     pass: 'pcpokemon',
     db: 'pc_pokemon',
     port: 3306,
     diaclect: 'mysql'
}

const db_sequelize = new Sequelize(
    db_info.db,
    db_info.user,
    db_info.pass,
    {
        host: db_info.host,
        dialect: 'mysql'
    },
)
export default db_sequelize
```

And here is the error output :

```
/usr/bin/node /home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha.js --ui bdd --reporter /home/yacine/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/WebStorm/ch-0/223.8836.27/plugins/nodeJS/js/mocha-intellij/lib/mochaIntellijReporter.js /home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/test/UserController.spec.js --grep ^Test all the trainer controller route\.  Test /users route with post method should return code response 201$

/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:359
    #initializeTTLTracking() {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index-cjs.js:5:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:25:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mysql2/index.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:49:14)
    at new ConnectionManager (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:30:21)
    at new MysqlDialect (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:13:30)
    at new Sequelize (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:194:20)
    at file:///home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/src/Database.js:11:22
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async formattedImport (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:9:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:42:28)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/esm-utils.js:100:20)
    at async singleRun (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/home/yacine/MEGA/Education/Informatique/Epita/EXP2/S8/Node.js/Projet/pc_pokemon/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:370:5)

Process finished with exit code 1
```